# Garbage Collecting Externally Loaded SWF Assets

Tags: actionscript-3, garbage-collection

I have this class that pulls out Library classes from a loaded .swf file. I noticed that everytime I remove the class from the stage somewhere in my App the class instance does not get Garbage Collected. Any suggestions?

```
package com.fullclip.utils {
import com.greensock.loading.LoaderMax;
import com.greensock.loading.SWFLoader;

import flash.display.DisplayObject;

public class LibraryAssets {

    public static function getAsset(id:String, librarySRC:String):DisplayObject     {
        return getAssetFromLoader(id, LoaderMax.getLoader(librarySRC) as         SWFLoader);
    }

    public static function getAssetFromLoader(id:String, library:SWFLoader):DisplayObject {
        try {
            var AssetClass:Class = library.getClass(id);
            return new AssetClass() as DisplayObject;
        }
        catch (error:Error) {
            Console.log("Could not find library asset: " + id);
            Console.warn(error, error.getStackTrace());
        }
        return null;
    }


}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how your custom classes/libs handle unloading or what utilities they offer to unload, but I'm sure somewhere in the code they end up using the Loader object. In that case, you need to explicitly call unloadAndStop(true) which gives a hint to the GC letting it know it can now collect and dispose on that loaded swf. See the docs for more: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Loader.html#unloadAndStop()

Comment: My swf's contain a lot of assets, I can't unload the whole swf because then I would need to reload it to get the assets back.

Comment: Then you cannot reasonably expect the GC to clean up the SWF, if you're still using it....

Comment: Yeah that seems to be a limitation of this method. In lieu of its convenience I am going to turn all sprites into bitmaps and keep a static version of the bitmapdata to use whenever I need. If I need to bring in MovieClips with animations I can bring them in as their own swfs.